# Nodemon keeps restarting server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an express server that uses a local json file for a database. I'm using https://github.com/typicode/lowdb for getters and setters.

Currently the server keeps starting and restarting without any problems, but can't access it. Below is my Server.js file:

```
import express from 'express'
import session from 'express-session'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import promisify from 'es6-promisify'
import cors from 'cors'
import low from 'lowdb'
import fileAsync from 'lowdb/lib/storages/file-async'

import defaultdb from './models/Pages'

import routes from './routes/index.js'

const app = express();

const db = low('./core/db/index.json', { storage: fileAsync })

app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/', routes);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);

db.defaults(defaultdb).write().then(() => {
    const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
      console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
    });
});
```

Anyone have an issue like this before? I think it has something to do with this line:

```
db.defaults(defaultdb).write().then(() => {
    const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
      console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the documentation:

> nodemon will watch the files in the directory in which nodemon was started, and if any files change, nodemon will automatically restart your node application.

If your db's .JSON file is under the watch of nodemon, and you're constantly writing to it, your server will restart in an infinite loop thus making it inaccessible. Try moving your .JSON file outside the scope of nodemon's watch via moving it outside your directory or via some nodemon configuration (if possible).

Comment: But I'm not constantly writing to the db. Only on startup to write the default db. Is my syntax wrong somewhere that's causing an infinite loop?

Comment: You may not be explicitly writing to it when your server boots, but it's possible that lowdb is writing to your .JSON file or another related file when your server starts.

Comment: @Dileet Also after reviewing the code, it would seem that this line is performing a write `db.defaults(defaultdb).write()`. Since it does this on start up, you will hit the infinite loop mentioned above.

Comment: Ok, so removing this worked. But how would I set the default db?

Comment: The key thing for me was that "something" in my app.js file was "writing". When I commented it out, all was fixed. Many thanks on the insight here.

Comment: Thank you.  I was troubleshooting this for an hour+.  I had a webscraping script that I accidentally left the "with open ..." uncommented out, so it was creating a new .json file in my root/server directory each run.  I wasn't looking there. #learningthingsthehardway

Answer (score 22):

I solved this issue from this page.

practically you just have to do

```
 nodemon --ignore 'logs/*'
```

Update: the link was hijacked and has been removed.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: it's true the links is broken  but i'm not the owner of the page, although you can try using  the command nodemon --ignore 'logs/*' and it works.

Comment: I use `nodemon --ignore 'sessions/*' index.js` because my sessions are written to files in the same dir.

Answer (score 11):

My solution: I've added **nodemonConfig** in **package.json** file in order to stop infinite loop/restarting. In **package.json**:

```
"nodemonConfig": { "ext": "js", "ignore": ["*.test.ts", "db/*"], "delay": "2" },
"scripts": { "start": "nodemon" }
```

Comment: Very nice. Add once to package.json and forget about it!

Answer (score 9):

I was puzzled by a constant stream of restarts. I started with **`nodemon --verbose`** to see what was causing the restarts.

This revealed that my package.json file was the culprit. I was running my installation in a Dropbbox folder and had just removed all files from my node_modules folder and done a fresh install. Another computer that shared my Dropbox folder was running at the time, and unknown to me, it was busily updating its node_module files and updating the Dropbox copy of package.json files as it did so.

My solution turned out to be simple, I took a break and waited for Dropbox to finish indexing the node_modules folder. When Dropbox finished synching, nodemon ran without any unexpected restarts.

Comment: I used this to diagnose the source, then the "--ignore" flag thats been suggested to fix.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (which is the same as the OP) just ignoring the database file worked

```
nodemon --ignore server/db.json server/server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generalized config file.
Name it `nodemon.json` and put in the root folder of your project.

```
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [".git", "node_modules/", "dist/", "coverage/"],
  "watch": ["src/"],
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "node -r ts-node/register"
  },
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "ext": "js,json,ts"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following code to the `package.json` file

```
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ext": "js",
    "ignore": [
      "*.test.ts",
      "db/*"
    ],
    "delay": "2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `package.json`:

```json
"nodemonConfig": {
  "ext": "js",
  "ignore": [
      "*.test.ts",
      "db/*"
  ],
  "delay": "2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `nodemon.json`:

```json
{
  "ignore": [
    "logs/*"
  ]
}
```