# Nodemon looping

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Dependency nodemon loops infinitely when trying to start the application

Any tips?

[image: CODE]

Comment: Nodemon is meant to run indefinitely? What’s the issue here?

Comment: @evolutionxbox  When running nodemon app.js, it keeps trying to start the application, but it's looping infinitely and doesn't start

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855839/nodemon-keeps-restarting-server could be helpful